# Vuetify Next - Range Slider Display Tooltip Between Range

Tags: vuetify.js

Currently I'm trying to implement a range slider like this one

[image]

With vuetify I didn't find a way to add a tooltip like the one in the example.

```js
            <VRangeSlider
                v-model="value"
                step="10"
                thumb-label="always"
                :min="0"
                :max="100"
                show-ticks
                persistent-hint
            />
```

Which results in something like this

[image]

Do you have any suggestions in how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no requirements, you can do this trick.

1. Create a box or a container(div).
2. Remove `thumb-label="always"` to disable the *label* of the slider(since we will display the value in the container).
3. Convert the value of slider and pass it to the container(div).

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
        value: [0,100]
    }),
})
```

```css
.box {
    margin-left: 40%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: dodgerblue;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
.box.arrow-bottom:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: -15px;
    border-top: 15px solid dodgerblue;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.7.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <div class="mb-5 box arrow-bottom">
            {{'$'+value[0]}} - {{'$'+value[1]}}
        </div>
        <v-range-slider
            v-model="value"
            step="10"
            :min="0"
            :max="100"
            show-ticks
            persistent-hint
        >
        </v-range-slider>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

BTW it's not clear what *vuetify version* is this, so I assume it's v.2

**EDIT**
I add this [Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) for vuetify 3.

Comment: I'm using vuetify 3.3 the only requirement would be to make this div move according to the range.
I'm sorry that I've didn't put this data in the question